# Dommarkers appear into incorrect position

Tags: here-api

I am adding markes using v3 Here Javascript api on the map shown on a website.
Adding a Marker object works perfectly, but when changing it to DomMarker the markers have a huge offset on the map and seem to get closer to their true position when zooming in. I've tried to search for similar issues, but could not find an answer. How can I get the DomMarkers shown in their true position correctly?

I am using Chrome browser.

Here's the code.

This works:

```
var icon = new H.map.Icon(svgMarkup);
var marker = new H.map.Marker({lat: startLat, lng: startLong}, {icon: icon});       
map.addObject(marker);
```

This does not:

```
if (obsIcon == null){
    obsIcon = new H.map.DomIcon(svgMarkup);
}
var marker = new H.map.DomMarker({lat: startLat, lng: startLong, ctx: 'GL'  }, {icon: obsIcon});        
map.addObject(marker);
```

EDIT: This is the code of the svgMarkup:

`var svgMarkup = '<svg width="20" height="20" ' + 'xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">' + '<circle cx="10" cy="10" r="5" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1" fill="'+ fColor+'" />'+ '</svg>';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe seems to be a common issue when the [anchor](https://developer.here.com/javascript-apis/documentation/v3/maps/topics_api_nlp/h-map-icon-options.html#h-map-icon-options__anchor) of your icon is incorrectly set. Your icon is offset by some pixels. That's why it seems that the marker moves closer to the actual position when zooming in.

Depending on what you icon looks like you may want to set the anchor when constructing your icon:

```js
// assuming your icon is 40x40 pixels (change values as necessary)
var icon = new H.map.Icon(svgMarkup, { anchor: {x: 20, y: 40} }); //bottom-center

icon.setAnchor({x: 0, y: 0}) //top-left
icon.setAnchor({x: 20, y: 20}) //center
icon.setAnchor({x: 40, y: 0}) //top-right
```

**EDIT**
You need to manually translate your icon to get the same effect as anchors on DomIcons.

```
'<div><svg width="20" height="20" ' +
   'xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" ' +
   'style="transform:translate(-10px, -10px)">' +
'<circle cx="10" cy="10" r="5" stroke="#000" stroke-width="1" fill="#ff00ff" />'+
'</svg><div>'
```

Note the div around the markup, as the DOM marker will put it's own transform on the outermost element. Then on the SVG inside I add a transform of -10/-10 to move the center of the circle to the top left corner. That should put your circle nicely at the center.

Comment: Many thanks for your support! This gives a great tip for me for another case, but for this problem this is not the case. By offset I mean really a huge offset, for example with zoom level 11 the offset is tens of kilometers on the map. The largest zoom level shows the markers few tens of meters from their true position. I have not set the altitude or ctx,

Comment: Next time I should read the question properly. DomIcons don't have an anchor... See my edit for an update solution.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! I added the <div> tags and then with the proposed fine tuning the markers are placed perfectly!